# How do I find the correct CRS for an ArcGIS REST server layer?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, arcgis-rest-api

I am having trouble with an ArcGIS REST server layer not showing up in the right place in QGIS. The server is: https://gis.geology.gov.kz/arcgis/rest/services/Public/Izy/MapServer

Sometimes when I add the layer it appears in the right place, but then after I change the styles, I find it has moved. Project CRS is EPSG:3857, and the layer CRS is 'RK_Equidistant_Conic'
Looks like the layer is centred on the Prime Meridian at Greenwich rather than in Kazakhstan?

[image]

Comment: Hi @Andy, you have added QGIS in the tags but not mentioning in your question. Did you miss out something?